# How can i only select the parameters corresponding to each month automatically?

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, rate

I have a table that includes data from two entire years, and i need to calculate the notification rate month by month in those two years. Because of that, i want to do the calculation with the data corresponding to one month.

In the example below i want to obtain the number of times a certain velocity appears in each month, so for example: if I select 1M/s, for January of 2017 the program should return 2, and 0 for the other months.

[image]

I have obtained the result for 1 month, but i want to change the start and finish of the counter each time the month changes automatically

```
numero1 = 1
numero2 = 1

parametro = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja4").Cells(4, 3)
'Velocidad
If parametro = ("Velocidad") Then
archivoConsulta = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja4").Cells(4, 4)
**For cont1 = 4 To 32**
parametro_avi = Sheets("hoja1").Cells(cont1, 56)
If parametro_avi = archivoConsulta Then
numero1 = numero1 + 1
End If
Next cont1
```

Comment: Hi! Please post your table structure and the specific desired output. This way it'll be much easier to help you. Also, as it seems that you're working with a database, please specify the rdbm you're using.

Comment: Is that a table in an SQL database? If so, you probably want to tag your question sql and also tag it with the brand of your database engine. This will be your best chance of attracting the attention of those who know to your question.

Comment: I have just uploaded an example, i hope you understand.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sounds pretty easy to do with some countifs

Comment: i have programmed the counter for counting one month, finishing counting when i see that the month changes in the excel table. But as i have much more data than in the example, i need to change the counting start and finish for each month automatically.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you programmed the counter? Could you please show what you've done so far? It's difficult to help without knowing where you are at the moment.

Comment: i just uploaded what i have done for calculating one month. I hope you understand